# GPS-data logger does not communicate to computer

Tags: usb, gps

I have a Canmore GPS-data logger Dongle GT-730FL/S does not work properly. Apparently, it's not possible communication between device and computer (ubuntu 13.10) to transfer data using USB port.

In the list of USB devices connected to the computer it appears as "Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port".

Then i want to know how can i access to this kind of device, to fix the problem or, at least to get information to fix the problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Follow some of the setup steps in this post to confirm you can connect to it, ignoring the Garmin specific setups:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GarminGPSMap76CSx

See if the xgps tool connects to it.

The second option is to try to use wine to run the Windows tools provided by the device manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like on my Ubuntu 22.04:

`dmesg`:

```
[ 4924.968633] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 4925.122299] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 4925.122303] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4925.122304] usb 3-1: Product: STM32 Virtual COM Port  
[ 4925.122305] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[ 4925.122306] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 036231693235
[ 4925.142882] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 4925.142912] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 4925.142913] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0483:5740 STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port
```

$ `find /dev -mmin -1  -ls`:

```
    1      0 drwxr-xr-x  26 root     root         5740 Jul  6 02:09 /dev
 1629      0 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root           80 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/serial
 1632      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           60 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/serial/by-id
 1633      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           13 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-STMicroelectronics_STM32_Virtual_COM_Port_036231693235-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
 1630      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           60 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/serial/by-path
 1631      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           13 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0 -> ../../ttyACM0
 1626      0 crw-rw----   1 root     dialout  166,   0 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/ttyACM0
    1      0 drwxrwxrwt   2 root     root            40 Jul  6 02:10 /dev/shm
  162      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root          4900 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/char
 1635      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            18 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/char/189:263 -> ../bus/usb/003/008
 1634      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            10 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/char/166:0 -> ../ttyACM0
    8      0 crw--w----   1 daniel   tty       136,   5 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/pts/5
    6      0 crw--w----   1 daniel   tty       136,   3 Jul  6 02:10 /dev/pts/3
  169      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           180 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/bus/usb/003
 1625      0 crw-rw-r--   1 root     root      189, 263 Jul  6 02:09 /dev/bus/usb/003/008
   87      0 crw-rw-rw-   1 root     tty         5,   2 Jul  6 02:10 /dev/ptmx
```

For seeing this, the device has to be turned on, otherwise it doesn't seem to communicate. Will post more, as soon I found a software for it.

Keyword: device also known as Renkforce GT-730FL-S GPS Logger